# How to use Arrays in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a select statement where in it might return more than one value. so I would like to store the selected values in a table kind of array since there is no concept of array in sql and also use the same stored values. My select query is as follows:

```
    if exists(
         Select StartDate,EndDate 
         FROM Reservations1  
         where (DateAdd(day,0,StartDate) >= @StartDate)
         and (DateAdd(day,0,EndDate) <= @EndDate) 
         and Requestid in
             (Select RequestId from RequestModelMap1 
              where ModelSerialNumber=@ModelSerialNumber)
         )
```

If it returns some values then i want to store it.

Comment: Which database system are you using (SQL Server, Oracle, etc)? Is this a stored procedure? How is it being interpreted? Please put more details on your question.

Comment: More details please - what exactly are you wanting to do with the values? And which values are they? For example your `IN` clause is effectively specifying an array of values (`RequestID`s) as an argument...

Comment: im using sql server 2008

Comment: from the select statement i get multiple returns for startdate and end date. so i want to store them..

Comment: i dont mind if i can select the values from "REquestModelMap1" other than what it is returning

Comment: Store them where? Temporarily for use later within the same routine? Or store them in a database table?

Comment: i want to store them temporarily and return the same as output

Comment: SQL Server does not support arrays if I'm not mistaken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the size of "array" you might just want to store it in `table variable`. Smaller sets I store in table variables, but larger I store in temp tables.

```
DECLARE @MyDateArray TABLE
    (
     StartDate DATETIME
    ,EndDate DATETIME
    )

INSERT INTO @MyDateArray
        ( StartDate
        ,EndDate
        )
        SELECT StartDate
               ,EndDate
            FROM Reservations1
            WHERE ( DATEADD(day, 0, StartDate) >= @StartDate )
                AND ( DATEADD(day, 0, EndDate) <= @EndDate )
                AND Requestid IN ( SELECT RequestId
                                    FROM RequestModelMap1
                                    WHERE ModelSerialNumber = @ModelSerialNumber )

SELECT *
FROM @MyDateArray
```

Comment: this is somewhat close to what i want. ok from whatever is stored in this temp table i would like to select values from this "RequestModelMap1" table other than what is there in temp table and return this as outpu

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how you will related your dates to `RequestModelMap1` table.  I'm not following your logic.

Comment: sorry its from table Reservations1

Answer (score 1):

Some pseudo SQL since I'm not sure what db system you are using:

```
-- create a table to store results
CREATE TABLE SelectedDates
(
  StartDate DATETIME,
  EndDate DATETIME
);


-- empty it
TRUNCATE TABLE SelectedDates

-- insert data
INSERT INTO SelectedDates (StartDate, EndDate)
    Select StartDate,EndDate 
     FROM Reservations1  
     where (DateAdd(day,0,StartDate) >= @StartDate)
     and (DateAdd(day,0,EndDate) <= @EndDate) 
     and Requestid in
         (Select RequestId from RequestModelMap1 
          where ModelSerialNumber=@ModelSerialNumber)
```

Comment: im using sql server 2008

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the values temporarily you can select into a temp table eg...

```
     Select StartDate,EndDate 
     INTO #temp
     FROM Reservations1  
     where (DateAdd(day,0,StartDate) >= @StartDate)
     and (DateAdd(day,0,EndDate) <= @EndDate) 
     and Requestid in
         (Select RequestId from RequestModelMap1 
          where ModelSerialNumber=@ModelSerialNumber)
     )

     --Show that values have been stored...
     SELECT * FROM #temp
```

However this may not been what you need - or the best way. You question requires more detail...

Comment: this is somewhat close to what i want. ok from whatever is stored in this temp table i would like to select values from this "RequestModelMap1" table other than what is there in temp table and return this as output

Answer (score 0):

Declare a table variable

```
Declare @temp Table
(
 startdate datetime,
 enddate datetime
)
```

Table variables are alive for duration of the script running only